# Data in Fragment saves its value even after finishing the activity

Tags: java, android, fragment

I have main activity that contains 4 fragments in tabs layout.

In one of my fragments I have the following fields

```
public class TemperatureFragment extends Fragment {
    static HashMap<Integer, String> imagesHashMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    static boolean isDrown;
}
```

and in my `onCreateView` I'm assigning values for them.

My problem raised in this scenario.

1. I set `isDrown = ture`.
2. Press on back button and user goes to previous activity.

When user goes back to the previous activity and then come back to the main activity `isDrown` should be false, But it's coming as true. It saves its value even when the activity is finished. Then I checked the hash-map size to see if it's saving the last value same as isDrown but it doesn't the size coming as 0.

I'm confused why `isDrown` not re-created and have value false as default? 
and how to solve this?

Comment: isDrown is static. A static variable is common to all the instances of the class because it is a class level variable.

Comment: Yes I understand that. But also from my understanding , when I finish the main activity the fragments will be destroyed and need to re-create them.So , then the isDrown variable should be re-defined with false.But I'm wrong , why? and how to rest the value then if finishing the activity is not enough?

Comment: No, your understanding is wrong, a static variable is a "class level" variable, after definition it is the same for all instances (even for new ones)

Comment: Opps , Yes you are right. Thank you